# parameters before Request.QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I am quite confused what's the difference between `=`, `$` and `#` before the `Request.QueryString`?

```
<a href='MyPage.aspx?Variable=<%= Request.QueryString["Variable"] %>'>Go to this page</a>
```

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

`<%= %>` is used for `Response.Write`, for example in `javascript` you can do this `var myVar = <%= CodeBehindVariable_Name %>` or you can do this in markup `<asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server"><%= TestString %></asp:Label>`,

and `<%# %>` is used for `Binding` in data controls like this : `<%# Eval("id") %>`
 ,

and `<%$ %>` is used for `Resources`, `ConnectionStrings`, `appSettings` , for example: `<%$ resources: ResourceKey %>`, or `<asp:SqlDataSource id="data1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings: MyConnectionString %>"/>`

you can read more [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx)

Comment: Could you explain further? I just started with VS so i'm not sure what any of those do.